# Android - Sending a notification upon recieving a new private message with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app in which users can send private messages to eachother.
I want a notification to be sent to a user when he recieves a new message.
Everywhere I looked it sayed using a cloud service such as FCM is needed.

I am storing each user's recieved messages in the Firebase database, I'm wondering why the following method wouldn't work:

1. Upon user login, Set a firebase reference on the user's Recieved Messages database node.
2. start an AsyncTask with an infinite loop:

   2.1 set OnDataChange event to listen to any changes in the user's Recieved Messages node

   2.2 Upon any changes alerted by OnDataChange, send a notification to the logged user that he recieved a new message.

would this work?

Comment: hello E.Mich you want notification on every message, is it like push notification? Add some code what you are trying so that we can figure out the exact problem.

Comment: Why use an AsyncTask? You already have Firebase which is a Real-time database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general what you are suggesting will work. (as @int j said there is no need for an infinite loop or AsyncTask though)

HOWEVER! The user's battery will not last very long with what you are proposing. It is not good practice to have listeners listening to the database all the time. While the app is in the foreground is fine, but when the app is in the background you should un-attach database listeners. This is why you would see many suggesting that you use FCM for notifying a user that a message is available.

Comment: thank you dear sir. just a general question if I may, if i initiate a firebase listener in an activity (or fragment), and i call the finish() method (or popbackstack), is the listener still active or is it detached together with its containing activity(/fragment)?

Comment: You could be causing a memory leak in that case, you should remove the listener in onPause.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the delay, but what where would then be the best place to put that database listener? I need a place that will be active at all times, no matter what screen the user is and if the app is in the foreground/background.

Comment: You would use a process outside of the mobile app, like on an app server. It would listen for changes and then send FCM messages to devices alerting them of the changes.